# Jenkins run external script with docker command

Tags: jenkins, docker

I'm trying to run a jenkins job with parameters. This job run an external script that invoke docker.

I added user jenkins user to docker group and restarted jenkins also. When I execute the script from a console is OK but from a jenkins build I got:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your group changes have not kicked in for docker yet; if you restart the system it will work. It might even be sufficient to log out the jenkins user completely and restart the docker service.  (sudo service docker restart).

Comment: Thanks ! It's works after a system reboot. But why from the console it was OK and not from jenkins ?

Comment: New session - the group changes hadn't kicked in for the jenkins user normally.  If you force a new session as them, it will have picked up the group changes.